# How to calculate $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}$ if I know $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Tags: integration

I need to calculate $\int \dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}$. I know that: $\int \dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = \arcsin{x} + \text{const}$.

But why then $\int \dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^4}} \ne \arcsin{x^2} + \text{const}$ ?

And how can it be calculated?

Comment: I need d(x^2) ?

Comment: @FaradayPathak But I need dx/sqrt(1-x^4), not (2x*dx)/sqrt(1-x^4)

Comment: As far as I know, it can be proved that this antiderivative does not have a closed-form in terms of elementary functions using differential Galois theory, especially appealing to differential forms on elliptic curves. (Notice that $dx/\sqrt{1-x^4}$ may be viewed as the differential form $dx/y$ over the hyperelliptic curve $y^2=1-x^4$.) To put simple, not only that none has figured out the answer in terms of elementary functions, it is in fact impossible to do so. Of course, closed forms involving transcendental functions (such as elliptic functions) are available, as in the answer below.

Comment: Because $\int \dfrac{dx^2}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}= \arcsin{x^2}+ \text{const}$

Answer (score 2):

The integral you need to calculate has no solution in terms of elementary function. Indeed, if you have a bit of knowledge of advanced maths, the result is expressed in terms of the so called Elliptic Functions.

In particular

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}\ \text{d}x = F\left(\left.\sin ^{-1}(x)\right|-1\right)$$

Where that symbol is indeed the Elliptic Function.

More details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral

For what concerns your case, as you may see there a little correlation between the simple integral and the Elliptic one. The argument of the Elliptic function is indeed the arcsine function (so you see, the apple doesn't fall very far from the tree).

Consider also this:

$$ \arcsin(x^2) = \int \frac{2 x}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}\ \text{d}x$$

Again it's about a subtle difference, an $x$ in this case.

Comment: @user376343 Ops! Thanks!

Comment: I guessed about arcsin(x^2), but it gives 2x in the numerator, but not 1.

Comment: @Student I don't understand your question. $2x$ *is* in Von_Neumann's numerator.

Comment: @Jam $\frac{2x \cdot dx}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)}} \ne \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)}}$

Comment: @Student I think Von_Neumanns point is that subtle differences in the numerator can determine whether the the integral elementary or not.

Comment: @Jam OK. How to calculate exactly this: $\int  \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1-x^4)}}$ ?

Comment: @Student That's literally what Von_Neumann's answer has described. Read the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is **not** generally true that if $\displaystyle \int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=F(x)$, then $\displaystyle \int f(x^2)\,\mathrm{d}x=F(x^2)$. To see how this doesn't work logically, look at the definite integrals:

$$\int_0^x f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=F(x)$$

$$\int_0^x f(t^2)\,\mathrm{d}t=\ ?$$

which is **not**

$$\int_0^{x^2} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=F(x^2)$$

The integral operator is not just a function of a single variable, $x$, it is dependent on **both** the function in the integrand and the bounds of the integral. The way the function $f$ is changed when its argument is squared determines the outcome, which is what we're interested in with the indefinite integral. A simple example showing it doesn't work (assuming $x$ is positive):

$$
\int x^{\frac{1}{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}+C
\\\ne
\\
\int\left(x^{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}x^{2}+C
$$

Comment: My problem is that: I can't come to $\int  \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1-x^4)}}$ from this $(arcsin(x^2)) ' = \frac{2x}{\sqrt{(1-x^4)}}$.